# Question on inverse functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If I have a function, say *f*, then would the mere existence of this function *f* also imply the existence of the inverse of the function? I am asking if it is necessary to also state that $f^{-1}$ exists. Or is it an immediate consequence that every function implies the existence of its inverse? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No. Only some functions have an inverse function, namely *invertible* functions. There are non invertible functions which have no inverse.

Comment: See [Inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function)

Comment: Unless you restrict the domain for a function failing the horizontal line test, the inverse exists, but is a relation or a function with different branches, like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=acos%28x%29+vs+-acos%28x%29%2B2pi+vs+acos%28x%29%2B2pi)

Answer (score 0):

No. Not every function has an inverse. In fact, **most** functions are not invertible. Even something as simple as a constant function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x)=C$$ doesn't have an inverse.